# Get EditTexts from referenced Activity

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, rhomobile

in my application I have an Activity A which has a reference to an Activity B. Now I am trying to get all EditTexts from Activity B in Activity A. In Pseudocode the code looks like:

```
public class A extends Activity{

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    BActivity B = BActivity.safeGetInstance();
    /**
     * Get EditTexts of Activity B here
     */
    }
}
```

I have no further information about Activity B since it does not belong to my Application. The only thing I know is that BActivity extends Activity. Is it possible to get the Edittexts of B?

Thanks in Advance

Tobi

Comment: Why do you need to get references from non-existent activity? if it is in backstack, you could send the data back to parent activity and update from onActivityResult. Explain your issue and problems you are facing. There should be better solutions .

Comment: I have to make the EditText noFocusable. I'm not able to edit the Layout.xml of Activity B since I'm extending a Framework where Activity B belongs to. Do habe any other idea how to solve this?

Comment: Why do you care about EditText when it is not visible to the user? You want to update the EditText when user goes back to the activity right? User startActivityForResult for that.

Comment: They will be visibile again after I finish Activity A. At this point in time they should not be Focusable anymore.

Comment: This is a terrible solution. Explain exactly why you want to do this and I am sure that there is a much better solution. Never hold references to `Activities` in Android.

Comment: I think this is just an example of very poor separation between the UI and the data itself.

Comment: Every time you give an `Activity`, `Fragment` or some other UI element the responsibility to hold some data for you instead of just displaying data then you are doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: I'm extending the Rhomobile Framework with a native extentsion for Android. Here is an example "https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes/blob/3-5-stable/lib/extensions/barcode/ext/barcode/platform/android/src/com/rhomobile/barcode/Barcode.java". To start your own Activity out of this framework you have to do it like: RhodesActivity ra = RhodesActivity.safeGetInstance();  Intent intent = new Intent(ra,A.class);
ra.startActivity(intent); Now I want to get the current Views in the RhodesActivity.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Alone the assumption that somehow two `Activities` can exist at the same time is completely insane on Android. Whatever framework you are using just don't use it... After minimizing your app when supposedly the other `Activity` still exists - even though it isn't being displayed - and leaving it like that for a while there are only two ways this can go down: either you get `NullPointerExceptions` like crazy or you create a memory leak. Android just does not work that way and no framework can change that. And if it tries to it is just going to create problems. Major problems.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using activity A (that is launcher), activity B does not exist yet. If you want to get data from activity B, use `startActivityForResult` method. It gives you back data after you destroyed B. So you cant get something from A when B hasn't created.

Activity B

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView yourView;
Button startA;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    yourView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);

    startA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);

    startA.setOnClickListener(this);

}


// start A on click
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
/**
 *
 * @param requestCode
 * @param resultCode
 * @param data - resultData from A
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    int dataFromA = data.getIntExtra("result",1);
    if(dataFromA == 0){
        yourView.setFocusable(false);
    }else{
        yourView.setFocusable(true);
    }
}
```

}

Activity A

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText etName;
Button btnOK;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);


    btnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
    btnOK.setOnClickListener(this);
}

//finished activity A and return to B with result
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("result", 0);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: Activity B already exists and calls my Activity A. You can say I'm extending the Framework where Activity B is in. But I can not send extra Data from B to A since it does not belong to my application.

Comment: Sorry, but its very hard to understand what is going on. Imagine that some activity B started activity A. After that action you just need to make no focusable some view in activity B. Why ? because after you finished work with activity A, activity B need to be with no focusable editText view ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason you should try this.

If the goal is to get the values inside of those EditTexts, you should store them somewhere in a database/preferences or maybe return them in onActivityResult().

Understand that Android gives no guarantees that the memory of other Activities is still valid. Activities get destroyed (and recreated) left and right.

If the goal is to communicate between applications (as you indicate), then this BActivity should make these values available, for example through a content provider.

Forget about solving this at GUI level.

Comment: The goal is to make the Edittexts in Activity B noFocusable. So you see no way to solve this without editing the class BActivity?

Answer (score 0):

Assume, you are in Activity A, and calling Activity B,

```
public void startNextActivity() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
  startActivityForResult(intent, SOME_UNIQUE_INTEGER_REQUEST_CODE);
}

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    boolean showEditText = data.getBooleanExtra("show", false);
    if (showEditText) {
      // handle your edit text visibility.
    }
}
```

In Activity B, somewhere when user leaves, (ex: `onBackPressed`)

```
Intent intent=new Intent();  
intent.putExtra("show", trueOrFalse);  
setResult(SAME_UNIQUE_INTEGER_REQUEST_CODE_YOU_SPECIFIED,intent);  
finish();//finishing activity
```

Now, when finished, `onActivityResult` will be fired in Activity A. Handle your UI state there.